# Kibana SSL PEM error on Windows

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, https, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

Note: I will regenerate all passwords and certs in my final install since I have provided all that information here. Also I have asked the same question here

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-ssl-pem-error-on-windows/117851/2

**Environment**

- Windows 10 Enterprises
- Elasticsearch Version : 6.1.1 (elasticsearch-6.1.1.zip)
- Kibana Version: 6.1.1 (kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64.zip)

**Problem:** 
I am trying to enabled SSL in kibana and I am running into an issue.  I cant for the life of me figure out what I have done wrong.  Here are the steps I have taken so far.

0) Create Yaml file use with the certutil `--in` flag.

> ```
> instances:
>   - name: node1
>     dns: ['node1.local']
>   - name: devws-kibana
>     dns: ['devws-kibana.local']
> ```

1) Declare variables for use in powershell commands

> ```
> $root = "C:\working\elasticsearch"
> [Version]$esVersion = "6.1.1"
> $es = "$root\elasticsearch-$($esVersion.ToString())"
> $esService = "elasticsearch_$($esVersion.ToString() -replace '\.','')"
> [Version]$KibanaVersion = "6.1.1"
> $kibana = "$root\kibana-$($KibanaVersion.ToString())-windows-x86_64"
> $kibanaService = "elasticsearch-kibana$($KibanaVersion.ToString() -replace '\.','')"
> ```

2) Install x-pack in elasticsearch

> ```
> `&"$es\bin\elasticsearch-plugin.bat" install x-pack --batch`
> ```

3) Create a Self Signed CA certificate.

> ```
>  &"$es\bin\x-pack\certutil.bat" ca --silent --pass password --ca-dn "CN=Elasticsearch-DevWS" --pem --out "$root\elastic-stack-ca.zip"
>     Expand-Archive -Path "$root\elastic-stack-ca.zip" -OutputPath "$root\certs"
> ```

4) Create a cert for elasticsearch and kibana

> ```
> &"$es\bin\x-pack\certutil.bat" cert --silent --pem --ca-cert "$root\certs\ca\ca.crt" --ca-key "$root\certs\ca\ca.key" -in "$root\instances.yml" --ca-pass password --pass password --out "$root\certificate-bundle.zip"
> Expand-Archive -Path "$root\certificate-bundle.zip" -OutputPath "$root\certs"
> ```

5) Copy Certs to proper directories

> ```
> Copy-Item -Path "$root\certs\ca\ca.crt" -Destination "$es\config\certs\ca.crt"
> Copy-Item -Path "$root\certs\node1\*" -Destination "$es\config\certs\"
> Copy-Item -Path "$root\certs\ca\ca.crt" -Destination "$kibana\config\certs\ca.crt"
> Copy-Item -Path "$root\certs\devws-kibana\*" -Destination "$kibana\config\certs\"
> ```

6) Update Elasticsearch.yml to below

> ```
> cluster.name: WRK001
> node.name: node1
> network.host: node1.local
> http.port: 9210
> discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [ 'node1.local' ]
> processors: 2
> node.master: true
> node.data: true
> node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
> xpack.ssl.key: certs/node1.key
> xpack.ssl.certificate: certs/node1.crt
> xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities: certs/ca.crt
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: full
> xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
> xpack.ssl.key_passphrase: password
> ```

7) Add secure key passphrase to keystore

> ```
> "password" |  &"$es\bin\elasticsearch-keystore.bat" add xpack.ssl.secure_key_passphrase --stdin
> &"$es\bin\elasticsearch-keystore.bat" list
> ```

8) Start Elasticsearch

9) Set password for build in accounts

> ```
> $url = https://node1.local:9210/
> $output = & cmd.exe /C "$es\bin\x-pack\setup-passwords.bat auto --url $url -batch" 2>&1
> Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black  $output
> ```

10) Parse passwords from response and save to temp files.

> ```
> $elasticPassword = ($output | Select-String -Pattern "^PASSWORD\selastic\s=\s(.*)$" -AllMatches).Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
> $kibanaPassword = ($output | Select-String -Pattern "^PASSWORD\skibana\s=\s(.*)$" -AllMatches).Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
> $elasticPassword | Out-File -FilePath "$es\config\elastic.password" -Encoding utf8
> $kibanaPassword | Out-File -FilePath "$kibana\config\kibana.password" -Encoding utf8
> ```

11) Remove setting `xpack.ssl.key_passphrase` from Elasticsearch.yml

12) Restart Elasticsearch

13) Verify Elasticsearch is work (and it is)

14) Install X-Pack in kibana

> `&"$kibana\bin\kibana-plugin.bat" install x-pack`

15) Update Kibana.yml to below

> ```
> server.name: devws-kibana
> server.host: devws-kibana.local
> elasticsearch.url: https://node1.local:9210/
> elasticsearch.username: kibana
> elasticsearch.password: nWD0zPDLFiM3yHdVQM9j
> elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ../config/certs/ca.crt
> ```

16) Start Kibana

17) Verify Kibana is running and I am able to log in with elastic user

18) Stop Kibana

19) Update Kibana.yml to below

> ```
> server.name: devws-kibana
> server.host: devws-kibana.local
> server.ssl.enabled: true
> server.ssl.certificate: ../config/certs/devws-kibana.key
> server.ssl.key: ../config/certs/devws-kibana.crt
> elasticsearch.url: https://node1.local:9210/
> elasticsearch.username: kibana
> elasticsearch.password: nWD0zPDLFiM3yHdVQM9j
> elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ../config/certs/ca.crt
> xpack.security.encryptionKey: 3qrb1xee9ue9rrh3p93ykj28otgp676iu0l8ziifjopfov6h4sv9jhyp49gpm90t
> ```

20) Try starting kibana. It fails and produces the following error.

> ```
> FATAL Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>     at Error (native)
>     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:69:17)
>     at Server (_tls_wrap.js:776:25)
>     at new Server (https.js:26:14)
>     at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:47:10)
>     at new module.exports.internals.Connection (C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\node_modules\hapi\lib\connection.js:88:74)
>     at internals.Server.connection (C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\node_modules\hapi\lib\server.js:142:24)
>     at KbnServer.exports.default (C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\http\setup_connection.js:43:10)
>     at C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\kbn_server.js:171:20
>     at next (native)
>     at step (C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\kbn_server.js:87:191)
>     at C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\kbn_server.js:87:437
>     at C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\kbn_server.js:87:99
>     at KbnServer.mixin (C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\kbn_server.js:187:7)
>     at KbnServer.<anonymous> (C:\working\elasticsearch\kibana-6.1.1-windows-x86_64\src\server\http\index.js:66:21)
>     at next (native)
> ```

**Documentation:**

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/tls-elastic-stack-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-filebeat
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/installing-xpack-kb.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/security-settings-kb.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/production.html#enabling-ssl
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/using-kibana-with-security.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/settings.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/certutil.html

**devws-kibana.key**

> ```
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
> DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,17D5A5CA90BECF38
>
> zOhDSJ8OFqB+FGvSmL18k4kIiojvO4yLnAmTYDar51NGAdvitBlGaOEvXzpBAx9j
> 3nwNVBvz+NCBMg9tOcr8UY9H1/Qgns7gpiWhCJmJlja33Jly97UJS9go6DHvWaJi
> OoppKOHOkFaDDnMo6XkyHN2PXagVxFJxO8zW1OgQjMn1dWzUN8jwff/hUmgLT1tx
> Arsso/+OKWEwZIJ2rczJjxXjgQmAu+d3libn8tLG9TpDStnj47j/8nxyViIp8Rq0
> fFv3XW2QN8oj0Pjo0IBP8FjjGc8+b+zq+kgfvs0Lz65k5GigUcL66nkAgXTADb0S
> 1Qxo8NVgC4yzc94WrMqSiV99Tlw1kCh1Sb86TJDjYvWMko04wP+kFJrIPs2IxA9D
> qxf7YwSZUHfIxg9FdNJHa+jHy+HinX9wOLK6JxZv5jWcZDNThjUW9JxRdvuM1nxD
> 6K0bUWAa8VlO0MU9x8Hwo7hhT4lJp6sr4jagKkvEqo/ZJWqyQzv5sOMQKu8vXGco
> nqjxApjTQGIplf+RrYaPg7URH6GdOW3cIY0d+Hh9i1K/v7UolO2fZjSoCaYmt4YF
> BjsMTIpdMnw1GfT0TlRa3bTgRAIqI9lE008fS/XRhjHgKY6wgHbbb7L+mxG05FIa
> 8rOAClu1btBJXZSELK4JqUgbY+kIPQqB2Ezh1FpggjTboJkdF2cXCazCLDtMSEi3
> z95miNGm3rRtS0HNaqrElDQeNbbyo6X9joFKApaxvdICDe9rfdMbhl/tQkYZdyxA
> XKeqbPL1dS95ma60A/7B0fIqwrD8Rko8q0EIMClG7bC/C7JRSdd8YEpIV9B1xorc
> gYyPiLtoGsihFpF2wpapG0e45wKedtl5QAYbeMWp9JoRPx9ZUuaP4Usn6zdyCqtw
> mWUGAHw2F7qQYpdvvUYrKAwC4dVRwivaHz4OoabppY0dYCq1THGvFBmlinbtDFLD
> ihKwgnvdACyhWU+e45a53cAtpSwoaPVenFvUJU6MHt+XmxT757blb4Dn9nsHqrwz
> HyWo0QoXdgbCwAzzBRW90R6wwYJx2cD+aYxpFop7aeeM/BgQ7IK2ejnykaTk3+NO
> hTJ1RgUDvn30jmczvJE0hquzn4SxKVi/hn+YuPxENc2a3CDbj6vsLQRGYMxjnSwT
> 4POYxc+hgszaE7afh2sKjQHwNboHpeLNuFOXDU22StsIbltWltw+jKzz3sHNE83G
> uUJnJPi7LN47WOT2pTNqV+k7/SEFfdo4JVDna54LF8LkrNLl9odmXR3ryTuTdQwP
> fAiNXWySIKfEJufVb4g0tv3xDFtJztwZrVvOgCnMnlXw+4BWp7FmN3M+pjDReEdv
> 1t15tPoDltCfPRva4bZaUXriYSYK5w6PW0t33AR7WbUSKmYlisqInCXwACjBjQJc
> nN8epVm33Kaqs18T1PSfkUKiqCKfFRqgleL5W96lG/W8b6qZvglod1qIu3k7qqiy
> V6d/jLpe/lASCy1mCtjnNMYTkIlNc5Jyy7FrplXGEm5dWLunMCnCAYX4rfAunynW
> 1YdB/poa9pXBbUPrF1KxHVNAmV7x5VS4/0eK7LKcUAWs01nH7yiBsXEfs3YfsVMQ
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```

**devws-kibana.crt**

> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIDbDCCAlSgAwIBAgIUMtq8dgtI+Opfy++z6Ptx8ci2Pr8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
> BQAwHjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTRWxhc3RpY3NlYXJjaC1EZXZXUzAeFw0xODAxMzAxOTUz
> NTNaFw0yMTAxMjkxOTUzNTNaMBcxFTATBgNVBAMTDGRldndzLWtpYmFuYTCCASIw
> DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKxUb4Mc9PVov9+r6a7V1At1+JL/
> CXl81g3tFQNYLzAMj/RJr06HAht8Loh7i7rBvWjleklOZNoKC8LMhbDNU56ix4WK
> 46yboRknYbjyEYOTjujx6gKoZ72yHugcbF5mc6GoafnyDJf0zL5nNHD8rC61WsFg
> hUzJF0qlA9dMojjMMrlrDJDIeKRzhrDj950QBgC9bzLVHQ0sseHmmPQFRQRXXYiP
> 7/89jfrclgsRaB/H7A2DI5JnZz/HvTQ7UiVOoRXb4TW3NMc1OQbkTg2bjpPMruL6
> tVXE/F0xLL4XXSUKbzT95p3vGxRp0jbnce0c8u4USiBEWoJbmYmD/rOouOECAwEA
> AaOBqDCBpTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUpbjtvSNDqoOha32Oculkz4L9c6kwWgYDVR0jBFMw
> UYAU3G6UbG/SC9ucNlVGjGZmwk/CQaehIqQgMB4xHDAaBgNVBAMTE0VsYXN0aWNz
> ZWFyY2gtRGV2V1OCFQDW6SMoh4MojBt5XyEkdFAA85u/jTAdBgNVHREEFjAUghJk
> ZXZ3cy1raWJhbmEubG9jYWwwCQYDVR0TBAIwADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEA
> Nr0wX2LqbIV8c4/tXaPUA34J8WoWS0HarADrFA+NFee3+/V0Afoun20HI8B8ql6a
> 5sK+omjDTsHxjjGIitatS/ntmOacJST4MLVeQzSHEfx3ArvozD0LJqnpCifvvUMz
> 0Gq1fmZHUioz3sHeqw4ZlpEll8MRyvtVj6gDQqzUJcaw9S06/J3VsEJbrRudhSLD
> GYgCz1P5jIsZoiEFhinWafgayImcYY3LMNdpRFwIbmwO4Uhs26vgt2zfRVW3vw6r
> +5O+DMvjoSe46fZN4uY36rCAEiCoYDC+PB6LSFOGbGswylTTL6F8EorQtjJxOnsn
> yFmugwITE4K4iwAQcuCy+g==
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```

**ca.crt**

> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIDWzCCAkOgAwIBAgIVANbpIyiHgyiMG3lfISR0UADzm7+NMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
> CwUAMB4xHDAaBgNVBAMTE0VsYXN0aWNzZWFyY2gtRGV2V1MwHhcNMTgwMTMwMTk1
> MzQ5WhcNMjEwMTI5MTk1MzQ5WjAeMRwwGgYDVQQDExNFbGFzdGljc2VhcmNoLURl
> dldTMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArB0kt1hdL0xuCqtw
> pO/9wr6xvL9uOy63uHWhEvF8hqW1Kv3w9unZQkJxXlQj3oVbhJTGD6+Bu6RZ8nwl
> J7kVjf3EHDvcvwZZElHjmV0zlZ8k3XlJJmKIFeCNAa52YpmReiFerIv+xWV9F4Ae
> B77O2pNzfvrJzWroPBVodbF9/N0kxplwSbAJPRGLDvknxW0vX3XiyjvDUPZkmVhm
> xc7g0XkTqtjGcYKylz3sfCEnBOSY+3TKePyA62thKlmfMb5iDxGHjraHCcXzPtjh
> y3LcD4E3KM57xv1XnHyrKxzJLf0iaJb1xyd4aRGFfckhkqrGvyaS08PRLd3RL+QE
> /JsRKQIDAQABo4GPMIGMMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTcbpRsb9IL25w2VUaMZmbCT8JBpzBa
> BgNVHSMEUzBRgBTcbpRsb9IL25w2VUaMZmbCT8JBp6EipCAwHjEcMBoGA1UEAxMT
> RWxhc3RpY3NlYXJjaC1EZXZXU4IVANbpIyiHgyiMG3lfISR0UADzm7+NMA8GA1Ud
> EwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAIA7S3HbOEKw9kTjxPYlOYoe
> kQiKTyZ7rxUAJYSnafnmsjbCMbpVXS9k+THm3IUTQuyxwrGuuBBeKFZJWQ1FcPiF
> DVPsgsNO4MRT6r78XjmCJJZcB5FZqbfK7EQd/E4sRzq8bk5VR6wfQK/U5/42TTcw
> 5RdDYnS4axLQOb9AuSdma7XP6BcshNAFCTp39caP7ZfKLJeRMMv0Mn0/3Yt9I9dv
> 2MGpxnMOYeVKzYVeoyXXDIOZqdPEkPO6gO7i1MprHcC3XlXFwkbe/EZ4pKUtRTJU
> kUgoSTOEd8BO8hwOYhG3HjOqTQe4U6lp2J58Kk47MMs8KUH5Zv47O8baNdHPWVw=
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. The server.ssl.certificate and server.ssl.key values were switched.